# How to create overlaying papers (pile) - CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css, image

Is their anyone who can help me create this effect:

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/avr0p1.png]

As you see in the bottom of the content, it looks like there are 3 papers "lying on each other"

How can this be obtained?

Comment: you do realize that the example you cite is a PNG, right?  It's not CSS... are you asking if this can be replicated in CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Overlayed Papers Demo with pure css/html](http://jsbin.com/ojuram/1/edit)**

Code used:

```
<style>

  #paper{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#fff;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    width:380px;
    height:470px;
  }
  #paper_foo1, #paper_foo2{
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    bottom:-8px;
    height:4px;
    width:370px;
    margin-left:3px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;
    border-left:2px solid #ccc;
    border-right:2px solid #ccc;
  }
  #paper_foo2{
    width:360px;
  }     
</style>


  <div id="paper">

    <div id="paper_foo1"><div id="paper_foo2"></div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow! This is awesome! Although, whenever I add it to my original CSS (the 1kb grid) it doesn't show the 3d effect

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to go pure CSS/HTML, you could probably do something like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    Content
    <div class="backpage"><div class="backpage"></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.backpage {
    z-index: -1;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

I haven't actually tested that out, but it should give you something similar to that. I'd prefer something dynamic, though...

Comment: obviously this would need to be tweaked a bit to fit that image more precisely. Looks like you probably have 2 or 3px borders with slightly rounded corners. But the idea feels sound.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/gHKh4/7/

Just play with the CSS to have it as you desire.

Preview:

[image: Preview of Paper 3D effect]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <h2><strong>Main window</strong></h2>
    <p>My content</p>
</div>
<div id="footer1">
</div>
<div id="footer2">
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}

#content, #footer1, #footer2 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#content {
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
 }

#footer1 {
    width: 79%;
}


#footer2 {
    width: 78%;
}

#footer1, #footer2 {
    height: 3px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though, this question is already answered, but i think this solution might be interesting to somebody. Only one div in HTML, everything done by CSS and pseudo-elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="page"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888;
    border-width: 2px;
}
.page:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 560px;
    height: 4px;
    left: 18px;
    top: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #888 #888 #888;
    border-width: 2px;
}
.page:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 520px;
    height: 4px;
    left: 38px;
    top: 206px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #888 #888 #888;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zTu9/

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a background image in css for a  with your content within. I am open to other suggestions.

HTML:

```html
 <div class="myDiv">
     <!-- content here -->
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .myDiv {
     background-image: url('threepapers.png');
 }
```

I would use PNG for the background image, because it allows transparency

Comment: Yeah. I would create a div that holds small background in the bottom. Just divide image into 2 parts.
<div><div class='content'>Content goes here.</div><div class='bottom'></div></div>

Comment: But as the papers in the bottom have a fixed width, how can I obtain to do this fluid?